# Custom Provider: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'provide' does not exist in type

Tags: typescript, testing, nestjs

I'm trying to replace my logger provider in a unit test file with a stubbed provider so that I don't get logs during unit tests from the tested module. I'm getting the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ provide: string; useValue: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'Type<any> | DynamicModule | Promise<DynamicModule> | ForwardReference<any>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'provide' does not exist in type 'Type<any> | DynamicModule | Promise<DynamicModule> | ForwardReference<any>'.  

    21           provide: WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER,
```

My Code:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [MyService],
      imports: [
        {
          provide: WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER, // Error on this line
          useValue: {},
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    MyService = moduleRef.get<MyService>(MyService);
  });
```

And here's the constructor of the module i'm testing

```
constructor(
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom providers go in the `providers` array, not the `imports`. Providers **never** go in the `imports` array.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to stub a dynamic module that's injected globally. It seems that I can't put the module in the providers array though. Do I need to figure out the specific module that we're using from this module and add it to the providers array here?

Comment: Why not use the `.overrideProviders` method provided by the `TestingModule`? https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing

Comment: That worked! Thank you!. I had to import the logger module in the imports array and then I was able to use `.overrideProvider(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER)` along with `.useValue({
        debug: () => {},
        error: () => {},
        info: () => {},
      })` to stub the logger. Thank you very much